# How to generate a javax.crypto.SecretKey from a String

Tags: android, string, encryption, cryptography, secret-key

The follow line allow me to generate a SecretKey

```
 SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
```

But I want to generate a SecretKey related to a specific String.

For example

```
String myKeyStr="abcde";

SecretKey mykey2=keyGeneratedFrom(myKeyStr);
```

Obviously the SecretKey generation should have a 1:1 link to avoid issue during the decryption.

I have no idea of how to solve this problem.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are not keys. You have to use something like PBKDF2 to derive a key from a password. Even then, it pays to have secure passwords. There is a lot of information about PBKDF2 when used in Java, and the Bouncy Castle library can help too.

- [PBKDF2 function in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091519/pbkdf2-function-in-android)
- [Java - PBKDF2 with HMACSHA256 as the PRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147463/java-pbkdf2-with-hmacsha256-as-the-prf)
- [PBKDF2 with bouncycastle in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674018/pbkdf2-with-bouncycastle-in-java)

Etcetera.

Don't forget to use a random salt.

Comment: Do you need any other info AndreaF?